# I cant get React Context to work with Typescript. This is probably a basic Typescript concept i'm not understanding

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I'm trying to set state in context with typescript.
However, Typescript is giving me an error that Todo[] is not assignable to type never.

This is what my code looks like:

```
type Props = {
  children: any;
};

interface Todo {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

function TodoContext({ children }: Props) {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<Todo[]>([]);

  return (
    <>
      <FilterContext.Provider value={[todos, setTodos]}>
        {children}
      </FilterContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

It's the todos in the value{} property that is giving me the error.

Any idea what i did wrong?

Thank you!

I'm not sure i feel like i set the state correctly. Don't understand why the value={} part is giving me an error.

Comment: Can you show us the line where you do `const FilterContext = createContext()`? You're probably not specifying the type on that line. `createContext` is a generic which you can use to define what the value's type is, such as `createContext<number>(3)`

Comment: This is it ```export const TodoContext = createContext([]);```, i renamed the TodoContext component name to TodoComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const TodoContext = createContext([]);
```

Since you don't specify the type on the value, typescript tries to infer it from how you're calling `createContext`. It sees that you passed in an array, but there's no way to tell what that array is supposed to contain, so it assumes `never[]`. Instead, you want a tuple where the first element is the todos array, and the second element is the setter function. This can be done like:

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

type ContextValue = [
  Todo[],
  Dispatch<SetStateAction<Todo[]>>
]

export const TodoContext = createContext<ContextValue>([[], () => {}]);
```

Comment: I don't understand half of this at all but it worked. I'm going to have to do some more reading on context. Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please explain to me in simple terms what a setter function does? And how dispatch and setStateAction are contributing to this? Thanks!

Comment: A setter function like `setTodos` instructs react to rerender the component. When it rerenders, the state has a new value. `And how dispatch and setStateAction are contributing to this?` Those are just some predefined types for the setter function. If you prefer to write it manually, `Dispatch<SetStateAction<Todo[]>>` is the same as `(value: Todo[] | (prevState: Todo[]) => Todo[])) => void`